# What's the meaning of "on-line" in the man page of man?

Tags: linux, manpage

```
$ man man
...
NAME
       man - an interface to the on-line reference manuals
...
```

What's the meaning of `on-line` here?

Comment: Not requiring dead trees. UNIX existed BCI - Before Common Internet.

Comment: What's the meaning of "Not requiring dead trees"? :-( @pst

Comment: Being able to read the documentation without pulling a huge Paper book off the shelf :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Available from the command line?  :)

"[On-line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_and_offline)" can mean available immediately/connected/ready to use, which accurately describes a manual contained within the system itself.  Considering the age of this, it may also refer to electronic manual as opposed to printed manual.

Comment: And without any network connection. The `man` page can be read even without wifi and without ethernet....